# Changing out GFCI disconnect for new hot tub

Tags: electrical, gfci, neutral, grounding-and-bonding

I purchased a new hot tub. On the current disconnect, using an ohmmeter, I get 0 ohms between the bare conductor and white neutral. I wired the original box and had it inspected but not sure how in-depth the code inspector looked it over.

Replacing the disconnect, I'm not sure if I should keep the neutral and bare wire separate or bond them together. At the main panel they are bonded but from what I read at the subpanel (near the hot tub) you should keep them isolated.

I live in PA

Answer (score 15):

Neutrals and grounds are kept separated everywhere except at the main panel.

Comment: Yup, and measuring zero ohms between ground and neutral is normal.  They are bonded to each other back at the main panel.

Comment: Most meters can not accurately measure resistance values below 1-2 ohms with #10 copper the smallest size ground in most all sub panels for hot tubs, 1000’ of copper only has a resistance 1.2 ohms larger conductors will have smaller resistance values so even with a long residential run you will have a value less than 1 and as the other answer states the only place neutral and ground are bonded in modern panels is at the main.